AWS ApiGateway: How can I view current settings for Access-Control-Allow-Headers
It looks like the only way to edit these values is to "Enable Cors" again from the Resource tab within API Gateway. However, I do not know the previous values set for Access-Control-Allow-Headers which can be a comma-separated list. I don't want to overwrite someone else's custom list of headers.
So if I go in and set my own custom Access-Control-Allow-Headers values, and then save, verify it works by re-deploying to a stage, that works great...but then if I come back in a few months and want to check what value is here, there doesn't seem to be a way to display it. Unless I'm missing something...?
